# SQL query to count the number of times a term appears if the term appears

Tags: sql, mariadb

I need to count the number of times the term appears only if it does appear.

I have a table built like the following:

```
document | term
a0000001 | n/a
a0000001 | for
a0000001 | nothing
a0000002 | lux
a0000002 | the
a0000002 | censoring
a0000003 | the
a0000003 | the
a0000003 | and
```

This query returns the count of the term that appears in each document:

```
SELECT document, COUNT(term) AS term_count
FROM documentsx
WHERE term="the"
GROUP BY document;

document | term
a000002  | 1
a000003  | 2
```

And this query tells me if the matching term appears:

```
SELECT document, SUM(CASE WHEN term='the' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "the"
FROM documentsx
GROUP BY documents;

document | the
a000001  | 0
a000002  | 1
a000003  | 1
```

I am looking for a way to combine these two two queries so that I get the following:

```
document | the
a000001  | 0
a000002  | 1
a000003  | 2
```

I'm using MariaDB.

Comment: Your second query has a syntax error.  In every RDBMS I'm aware of [the corrected version generates exactly the results you want](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fdf36/2).  This implies that either MariaDB is doing something _non-standard_ (and **dangerously** so), or something more is going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with MariaDB but in SQL Server I was able to use a UNION to get the combined results you wanted.

Comment: ...how?  **Please** provide an example, because otherwise this should be closed.  Especially as there are a minimum of two ways to use that clause here.  Use of `UNION` in this case is likely to be less performant than other solutions available.